# CGIHTTPServer running with OS X 10.8.4 error 404

Tags: python, macos, cgi

I have the simple python script below, hellocgi.py

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Content-type: text/html \r\n\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("<!doctype html><html><head><title>Hello CGI</title></head>")
sys.stdout.write("<body><Hello CGI</h2></body></html>")
```

The file is placed in the directory

```
/Users/MyName/cgi-bin
```

Then I change the permissions

```
chmod +x hellocgi.py
```

and run

```
python -m CGIHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

If I open a browser with `http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/hellocgi.py,` I get:

```
Error response
Error code 404.
Message: No such CGI script ('/cgi-bin/hellocgi.py').
Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.
```

Can anybody tell me what's happening? I also tried to pace the scripts in /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables , but that does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The script needs reading permission, not execution permissions. The python interpreter executes, the script is just read from the file system.

Comment: Thank you. Changing permissions to read did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the error you listed with an invalid (non-existant) path, 
and so I suggest you re-check what directory you are using as well as
the spelling of the filenames and urls.

As per the docs [1], 
  "This class is used to serve either files or output of CGI 
   scripts from the current directory and below"
CGIHTTPServer works with the directory tree rooted at the directory in
which it is run.  Accordingly, you should pick some directory ($HOME
works, as would /tmp/www/ if you want to just do some testing), setup
the files you want to serve, and start the server from the directory.

[1] http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Path directories and spellings are fine; I suspect the problem has to do with the Python version for CGIHTTPServer and for the script..still trying to figure out what's wrong, but won't spend too much time with it and move to flask